# Apollo client uri configuration inside docker

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm running three of my services inside docker containers

```
container 1 => nginx (for routing)
container 2 => nextjs app (client)
container 3 => apollo server (on top of express)
```

Is it possible to have direct access to server(container 3) from the client (container 2) ?

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://api", // <=== this gives following error
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

Error: request to http://api/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.3:80
```

here is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - client
      - api
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - "api:server"
    volumes:
      - /client/node_modules
      - ./client:/client
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - /server/node_modules
      - ./server/src:/server/src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `api` exposes a port, then yes.

The error suggests that `api` is **not** exposing the default port (`80`) used by `http://api/`

The Docker Compose defines the container port `4000` (the value of `Y` in `X:Y`) for `api` and exposes this port on the host (also as `4000`, the value of `X` in `X:Y`).

If that is accurate, then you'll need to reference the port as `http://api:4000/`.

> **NOTE** The `ports` array only defines port mappings between the host and the container but you must ensure that the container port referenced is indeed exposed by the container.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! I forgot the port. I was looking for nginx conf file proxy_pass http://api;. Thanks @DazWilkin